# Data versioning with FluentMigrator

Tags: fluent-migrator

We need to have the reference data versioned in our Database project (using FluentMigrator). I know it's easily possible with `Migrations` but the problem is we have different reference data for the different environments (Develpment, Test, Production).

`Profiles` would not work for us because there is no versioning there.

We would like to have only one Database project. One idea could be checking `Environment Variables` in Migrations and performing different actions (inserting different dara) based on them.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement could be accomplished by using Tags.

More info:

https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Filter-migrations-run-based-on-Tags